# Type conversion by "explicit operator X" for static_cast or toX()?

Tags: c++11, casting, static-cast

There are similar previous questions, but all the ones I could find ask different questions:

- [static_cast vs. direct call to conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629474/static-cast-vs-direct-call-to-conversion-operator) - Related but different, discusses `static_cast<string>(x)` vs `x.operator string()`
- Many talking about `static_cast` vs c-style casts (often referring to it as function-style casting)

---

What are things I should consider when deciding how to implement explicit conversion on a class?

In c++11, I can have an explicit conversion operator:

```
class myClass {
public:
   explicit operator std::string() const {
      ...
   }
};
const myClass x{...};
std::string str = static_cast<std::string>(x);
```

Or, I could have a function `toX()`:

```
class myClass {
public:
   std::string toString() const {
      ...
   }
};
const myClass x{...};
std::string str = x.toString();
```

Part of me is thinking they're identical, but part of me is thinking I must be missing some scenarios or best practice guidelines.

Granted `static_cast` allows a call to `myClass::explicit operator std::string()` or `std::string(myClass)`, but I'm focused on at the point where the decision has been made to have the conversion take place within `myClass`, like here where `std::string()` doesn't have a conversion constructor, so this distinction doesn't come into play.  And, it also allows casting between inheritance hierarchies, but that doesn't come into play here either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing both, assuming your class is enough "like" a string that a conversion to `std::string` really makes sense.  (Of course, one member function can just call the other.)

When I want to actually construct a named object using an explicit conversion, writing it as a direct-initialization is sometimes a bit more natural:

```
std::string s1{ x };            // Plain conversion.
std::string s2 = x.toString();  // More verbose - could be good or bad
```

But when I don't need a named object, calling a member function is much nicer-looking than needing to use some form of cast:

```
f( static_cast<std::string>(x) ); // Blah.
f( x.toString() );                // Convenient.
```

Just be sure to document that the two ways of doing it are identical.